# Redirect '/' to a specific route in react-router 4 at app start

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, redirect, react-router

I am trying to redirect my application to a specific route at starting of app. I tried this

```
 <Route exact path="/todos" component={Todo} />
 <Route exact path="/users" component={User} />
 <Redirect path="/" to="/todos" />
```

But It has 2 issues

1. It redirects me on the todos route on refresh
2. It gives me following warning

`You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/todos"`

I want to achieve the redirection concept as it is in Angular like we do:

`{ path: '', redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch: 'full' },`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to wrap them in a `<Switch>`, for example:

```
<Switch>
 <Route exact path="/todos" component={Todo} />
 <Route exact path="/users" component={User} />
 <Redirect from="/" to="/todos" />
</Switch>
```

It will match the routes in order. So for example: if you have /todos, it will match the first one, if you have /users, it will match the second one, for "/" it will redirect to "/todos"

Also Redirect has `from` and `to` props. Your example has `path` instead of `from`